# How to Combine Two Columns from Two different Queries with Different Datatypes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I'm trying to ultimately get a sum of two columns. The issue is that the sum is made up from two different tables. Basically it's tbl1-col1 + tabl2-col1.

I'm attempting a UNION ALL, but the issue is that for me to pull the right data from both queries to even get the right data in the col1's, I need to SELECT different parameters for both queries.

Obviously I'm working with different datatypes and header titles, so that UNION isn't going to work the way I want it to.

```
-------------------------------query 1------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    RECEIVABLE_LINE.AMOUNT AS Total,
    RECEIVABLE_LINE.INVOICE_ID, 
    RECEIVABLE_LINE.LINE_NO,  
    RECEIVABLE_LINE.GL_ACCOUNT_ID, 
    RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE, 
    RECEIVABLE.TYPE


FROM RECEIVABLE_LINE INNER JOIN RECEIVABLE ON RECEIVABLE_LINE.[INVOICE_ID] = RECEIVABLE.[INVOICE_ID]
WHERE RECEIVABLE_LINE.GL_ACCOUNT_ID LIKE '4%'
AND RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND RECEIVABLE.INVOICE_DATE < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0)

-------------------------------query 2------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
    SUM(SHIPPER_LINE.USER_SHIPPED_QTY*CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE) AS 'Total',
    SHIPPER_LINE.USER_SHIPPED_QTY,
    CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE,
    SHIPPER.INVOICED_DATE,
    SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE
    --SUM(isnull(CAST('Total' AS decimal),0)) as 'Total of all totals'


FROM SHIPPER_LINE INNER JOIN SHIPPER ON SHIPPER_LINE.PACKLIST_ID = SHIPPER.PACKLIST_ID
LEFT JOIN CUST_ORDER_LINE ON SHIPPER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO = CUST_ORDER_LINE.LINE_NO AND SHIPPER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID = CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID
WHERE SHIPPER.INVOICED_DATE Is Null
AND SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-10'
GROUP BY SHIPPER_LINE.USER_SHIPPED_QTY, CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE, SHIPPER.INVOICED_DATE, SHIPPER.SHIPPED_DATE
ORDER BY SHIPPER.INVOICED_DATE
```

What are my options at this point?

Comment: Show some sample data and expected results... its not clear from your question exactly how you want to combine them.

Comment: Are you looking to combine the Amount totals summarized by INVOICE_DATE?  Or would the tables be matched on INVOICE_ID and LINE_NO?  It's not clear how it fits together

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. It's hard for me to articulate this properly because I'm newer to SQL. Does it make sense that I need to take the "Total" columns from both queries and add them together into a sum? That's my ultimate goal.